# How can BERT/Transformer models accept input batches of different sizes?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface

I understand that all inputs in a batch need to be of the same size. However, it seems BERT/Transformers models can accept batches with different sizes as input.

How is that possible? I thought we needed to pad all examples in a batch to `model.max_input_size`, however, it seems HuggingFace does `Dynamic Padding` that allows sending batches of different lengths (till the time they are smaller than `max_input_size`)

[image]

Link: https://mccormickml.com/2020/07/29/smart-batching-tutorial/
Link2: https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/en/chapter3/2?fw=pt#dynamic-padding

Comment: Food for thought, can you do a `np.dot(x, y)` for different sizes of x and y? Modern transformers models are basically lots of matrix multiplication, i.e. lots of dot products. Take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/code/alvations/how-to-fine-tune-an-opus-mt-model/ =)

Comment: See also https://github.com/bytedance/effective_transformer

Answer (score 0):

In order to group samples of the same length in the training process, you can use the HuggingFace `Triner` and `TrainingArguments`.

In this case, you can set the parameter `group_by_length` to `True`.

You can find more details in HuggingFace [`Trainer`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/trainer) and [`TrainingArguments`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.32.0/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments) documentation.